# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR after http2 enabled

Tags: ssl, http2

I'm setting HTTP2 for my application and I get randomly ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR onm y browser. I was using Let's Encrypth to encrypt with SSL and everything was working well. The problem occurend after I have enabled HTTP2 today. I'm using Apache. I updated it to 2.4.38 to support HTTP2 module

I tryed the following :

- disabling http2 module / restarting apache2
- clearing all the browser cache
- resetting the HSTS header using the virtual host :

  Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0; includeSubDomains;" env=HTTPS

No results, still have randomly the error.

Comment: Your question is probably more on topic for [sf] or [su] or [webmasters.se] (read their help section to see what is on topic), since for now there is nothing related to programming in your question and StackOverflow is about programming related questions.

Comment: thanks, i moved it to Super User

Comment: Since it also happens without http2 this seems to be due to a bad Apache set update. Anything in the error logs?

Comment: @BarryPollard thanks for your answer. I looked at /var/log/apache2/error.log and I only found a pagespeed caching error. what is wired is that I see http2 requests event with the disabling it with a2dismod http2, is it normal ?? https://imgur.com/6gKgcx2

Comment: The first one is loading Google Fonts (as it’s using QUIC). Add the domain column to see. Not sure on last one. Is that your domain? Did you restart after turning off?

Comment: actually, the requests are not made to my server, my bad. no requests even when http2 is enabled actually... any other idea ? is there other logs to check ?